# Trouble using filter and str_detect to remove participants

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am conducting food related study and would like to remove all of a participants data if they identified that they have any food related allergies during the questionnaire part of my study. I am trying to accomplish this using group_by, filter and str_detect.

Unfortunately, the code I have at the moment results in a new table, with only the answers with "gluten". The group_by function also does not function as expected, as it doesn't remove all the participants answers, only the rows that contain "gluten".

Here is the code I have now. I would like all of a participants answers tobe removed if they answered "gluten" anywhere in the question:)

```
  my_data_raw_quest %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  filter(
    str_detect(dv, "(G|g)luten"))
```

Here is the table created from that code.

```
structure(list(session_id = c(53877, 53891, 54090, 54469, 54929, 
55038, 55061, 55096, 55104, 55108, 55145, 57068, 57074, 57146, 
57276, 57435, 57952, 58817), project_id = c(495, 495, 495, 495, 
495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 495, 
495), quest_name = c("Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", 
"Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic", "Sociodemographic"
), quest_id = c(2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 
2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189, 2189), 
    user_id = c(47667, 47681, 47877, 48251, 48705, 48816, 48839, 
    48873, 48881, 48881, 48921, 50663, 50723, 50794, 50924, 51077, 
    51561, 52161), user_sex = c("male", "female", "female", "female", 
    "female", "na", "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", 
    "female", "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", 
    "female"), user_status = c("test", "test", "guest", "guest", 
    "registered", "guest", "guest", "guest", "test", "test", 
    "guest", "registered", "guest", "guest", "guest", "guest", 
    "guest", "test"), user_age = c(59, 40, 35, 38, 53.7, 28, 
    21, 65, 24, 24, 25, 20.8, 38, 44, 32, 34, 44, 20), q_name = c("food allergies", 
    "food allergies", "food allergies", "food allergies", "food allergies", 
    "food allergies", "food allergies", "food allergies", "food allergies", 
    "food allergies", "food allergies", "food allergies", "food allergies", 
    "food allergies", "food allergies", "food allergies", "Other", 
    "food allergies"), q_id = c(92827397, 92827397, 92827397, 
    92827397, 92827397, 92827397, 92827397, 92827397, 92827397, 
    92827397, 92827397, 92827397, 92827397, 92827397, 92827397, 
    92827397, 92831398, 92827397), order = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4), dv = c("Gluten", "Gluten, cumin, paprika, anchovies", 
    "Gluten intolerance", "Dairy, gluten some veg, fruit and nuts", 
    "Gluten", "Gluten", "Gluten intolerant", "Gluten", "No allergies, but intolerant to gluten", 
    "No allergies, but gluten intolerant", "Lactose & gluten", 
    "gluten and dairy intolerance", "Sensitive to gluten and soy", 
    "Gluten", "Gluten", "Gluten", "Locked down with family, sister is gluten free", 
    "I am conscious of what gluten i eat as it sets my eczema off"
    ), starttime = structure(c(1607970136, 1607970692, 1607975785, 
    1607984805, 1608023741, 1608037872, 1608041491, 1608047134, 
    1608048524, 1608048811, 1608055657, 1609950997, 1609951334, 
    1609953692, 1609961095, 1609976350, 1610182572, 1610465355
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), endtime = structure(c(1607970180, 
    1607970791, 1607975825, 1607984927, 1608023787, 1608037944, 
    1608041525, 1608047239, 1608048613, 1608048856, 1608055709, 
    1609951071, 1609951428, 1609953730, 1609961133, 1609976399, 
    1610182657, 1610465458), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), undergraduate = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), NoUni = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Masters = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
    Postgraduate = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), degree = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), row.names = c(NA, -18L), groups = structure(list(user_id = c(47667, 
47681, 47877, 48251, 48705, 48816, 48839, 48873, 48881, 48921, 
50663, 50723, 50794, 50924, 51077, 51561, 52161), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9:10, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `filter(df, q_name != "food allergies")`

Comment: doesnt work for me unfortunately, thank you though!:)

Comment: replace df with your data, 'my_data_raw_request'. It'll be helpful if you show your desired outcome

Comment: Your example data set doesn't have any cases that have the word "gluten" anywhere at all, so it's difficult to determine what you expect.

Comment: Hey Ali, yes you are correct sorry that's such a dumb mistake. I corrected my answer now to include the table that my faulty code creates!

Comment: Ok, this table now has all cases that have the word "gluten" in it. If you want the opposite of what your code is currently doing, add a `!` before `str_detect()`: `... %>% filter(!str_detect(dv, "(G|g)luten"))`

Comment: thank you so much Phil!! that works perfectly:) sorry to bother but do you know if I have used the group_by function correctly? It still is not removing all the participants that answered in that way:(